# Recovering the inputs to Boolean circuits after partial evaluation

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lo.logic, circuit-complexity

This question discusses [Boolean Circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit) and Boolean functions from $n>1$ inputs to one Boolean output. Notation: $\textit{arity}(\mathcal{C})=n$ if $\mathcal{C}$ takes $n$ inputs, similarly for functions. Small letters like $a,b,c$ will denote Boolean inputs to the circuit or function. Small letters like $x, y, z, ...$ will denote results of Boolean gates inside the circuit. Symbols will symbolize Boolean operations: $\land$ for AND, $\lor$ for OR, and $\lnot$ for NOT. Values are as follows: $T$ for True, $F$ for False. Finally, $\textit{size}(\mathcal{C})$ is the size of circuit $\mathcal{C}$: the total number of gates in $\mathcal{C}$.

Consider circuits which take $n$ inputs. Choose $k<n$. We wish to study the effects of [partial evaluation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialEvaluation.html) of circuits for $k$ inputs out of those $n$ inputs.

Acknowledging the similarity to [reversible computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing), we begin with a motivating example.
Consider the circuit $\mathcal{C}_{1}$: $x= a \land b$. Let $k=1$. If we set $a = F$, then the whole circuit evaluates to $x = F$. Partial evaluation allows the AND gate to be eliminated from the circuit because one of its inputs is false. Alternatively, if we set $a = T$, then partial evaluation of the circuit evaluates to $x = b$; we can visualize this as an AND gate that is still awaiting an input from $b$. So we see that the circuit gives two different outcomes depending on the value applied to $a$.  So if we're told that $x = b$ is the result, we can infer that
$a = T$ was the original value. So we say that $a$ is *partially recoverable* from $\mathcal{C}_{1}$ because we can infer the value of $a$ when $a = T$ but not when $a = F$. Note that the input to a NOT gate is always *fully recoverable* because we can infer both true and false values: if the value of the NOT gate is true, we can infer that the input was false and vice versa.

We also observe how recoverability is affected after a gate is evaluated. Specifically, an AND gate whose value is true allows recoverability of both inputs (they're both true), but an AND gate whose value is false does not allow recoverability of any input since either of its inputs or both could be false. The situation is similar for an OR gate: if the gate evaluates to false, we know both inputs are false, but if the gate evaluates to true, it's true because either input or both is true.

More generally, $k$ inputs $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, ...,a_{k} \}$ are *fully recoverable* from circuit $\mathcal{C}$ if all possible values (true and false) of $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, ...,a_{k} \}$ can be inferred from the partially evaluated circuit $\mathcal{C}$ on those inputs. The idea is that we want to perform the maximum possible (perhaps partial) evaluation of the circuit and recover as many input values as possible.

Finally, we want to make sure order doesn't matter, so we introduce another concept: if a circuit $\mathcal{C}$ has $n$ inputs $I = \{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, ... ,a_{n} \}$ and $k<n$, and *every* subset of $I$ of size $k$ is fully recoverable, we say that $\mathcal{C}$ is *isotropic* for size $k$ full recoverability. For notational convenience later, let's box up this concept as a function and say $r(\mathcal{C})$ = max$\{k \mid \mathcal{C}$ is isotropic for size $k$ full recoverability$\}$.

Let $c$ be a constant in what follows. Consider the set of all circuits which accept $n$ inputs and whose size is polynomially bounded:

$$ S = \{\mathcal{C} \mid \textit{arity}(\mathcal{C})=n \, \, \text{and} \, \, \textit{size}(\mathcal{C}) = O(n^c)\}$$

Finally, let $k_{\max(n)}$ be the number of variables in the circuit in $S$ which allows the maximum full recoverability:

$$ k_{\max(n)} = \max \{ r(\mathcal{C}) \mid \mathcal{C} \in S \} $$

**Question 1:** Is $k_{\max(n)}$ always sub-linear as shown below and how would one prove it? Or intuitively, can we be sure that the number of fully recoverable variables in a Boolean circuit is always less than linear? Perhaps there is a reduction to some other P-complete problem which will make the whole thing easier?

$$ k_{\max(n)} = o(n) $$

**Question 2:** If the answer to Question 1 turns out to be false, that is, there is a linearly fully recoverable circuit, then does there exist a Boolean function $f$ where all circuits which compute $f$ must be linearly fully recoverable? That is,

$$ \exists f \forall \mathcal{C} ((\mathcal{C} \, \textrm{computes} \, f) \rightarrow (r(\mathcal{C}) = \Omega(n))) $$